# How to EMR S3DistCp groupBy properly?

Tags: amazon-emr, distcp, s3distcp

I am using aws .net sdk to run a s3distcp job to EMR to concatenate all files in a folder with --groupBy arg. But whatever "groupBy" arg I have tried, it failed all the time or just copy the files without concatenating like if no --groupBy specified in the arg list.

The files in the folder is spark saveAsTextFiles named like below:

part-0000
part-0001
part-0002
...
...

```
step.HadoopJarStep = new HadoopJarStepConfig
            {
                Jar = "/usr/share/aws/emr/s3-dist-cp/lib/s3-dist-cp.jar",
                Args = new List<string>
                {
                    "--s3Endpoint=s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
                    "--src=s3://foo/spark/result/bar" ,
                    "--dest=s3://foo/spark/result-merged/bar",
                    "--groupBy=(part.*)",
                    "--targetSize=256"

                }
            };
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After all the struggling with this whole day, in the end I got it worked with the groupKey arg below:

```
--groupBy=.*part.*(\w+)
```

But even if I add `--targetSize=1024` to args s3distcp produced 2,5MB - 3MB files.
Does anyone have any idea about it?

** ***UPDATE *** **

Here is the groupBy clause which is concatenating all the files into one file, in their own folder:

```
.*/(\\w+)/.*
```

The last "/" is so important here
--source="s3://foo/spark/result/"

There are some folders in "result" folder:

```
s3://foo/spark/result/foo
s3://foo/spark/result/bar
s3://foo/spark/result/lorem
s3://foo/spark/result/ipsum
```

and in each folder above there are hundreds of files like:

```
part-0000
part-0001
part-0002
```

`.*/(\\w+)/.*` this group by clause group every file in every folder so in the end you got one file for each folder with the folder name

```
s3://foo/spark/result-merged/foo/foo -> File
s3://foo/spark/result-merged/bar/bar -> File
s3://foo/spark/result-merged/lorem/lorem -> File
s3://foo/spark/result-merged/ipsum/ipsum -> File
```

So, this is the final working command for me:

```
s3-dist-cp --src s3://foo/spark/result/  --dest s3://foo/spark/results-merged --groupBy '.*/(\\w+)/.*' --targetSize 1024
```

Thanks.

Comment: i have a very similar problem to what you had but my folder is a bit more nested..Can you please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46833387/using-groupby-while-copying-from-hdfs-to-s3-to-merge-files-within-a-folder