# s3-dist-cp groupby Regex Capture

Tags: regex, amazon-s3, amazon-emr, distcp, s3distcp

I'm using EMR to combine hundreds of thousands of very small (1-5) row csv files. I want to concatenate them into around 100MB files so they are easier to work with.

My EMR job uses command-runner.jar with args:

```
s3-dist-cp --src=s3://surge-experiment-hourly-data/snapshot_day_zl_2023-09-17/ --dest=s3://surge-experiment-hourly-data/combined_test/ --groupBy='.*(csv)' --targetSize=100
```

Logs show it fetches all file info but then:

```
2023-10-30 21:33:34,930 WARN com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.S3DistCp (main): No. of files to copy should be greater than 0
```

Example file:

```
Bucket = fake-data-bucket, Key = snapshot_day_zl_2023-09-17/snapshot_day=2023-09-18 00%3A00%3A00/site_id=DZZ1/part-07747-e878e452-0754-44f6-ae9a-d822e42f2bf1.c000.csv
```

I'm thinking this is an issue with the regex in the groupby, somehow not identifying that these files match. But checking on regex101, they seem to match.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to EMR S3DistCp groupBy properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38374107/how-to-emr-s3distcp-groupby-properly)

Comment: No. That example their regex matched, but their capture group was wrong so it wasn't grouping how they wanted. My regex seems correct to me but isn't matching. How can .*(csv) not match any csv file?

Comment: All it does seem from that as well as from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46833387/using-groupby-while-copying-from-hdfs-to-s3-to-merge-files-within-a-folder) is that contrary to normal regex when a forward slash means ignore whitespace/verbose, it's used (necessary?) to show directory structure. Trying that now. It's unclear if all are needed from base s3: or just steps from the src

Comment: Does 's3://surge-experiment-hourly-data/combined_test/' location contains the CSV-files directly or in a subfolder like 'snapshot_day=2023-09-18 00%3A00%3A00/site_id=DZZ1/'?

Comment: It's in the subfolder as you suggest. My example file has the example full path.